# Не подключается фaйл в sass

Tags: sass

Установил в config.rb:

```
add_import_path "bower_components/foundation/scss"
```

Структура файл сист:

```
(папка)bower_components

(папка)sass > style.scss > проставил @import "normalize";

(папка)css

(файл) config.rb
```

Ошибка при sass -watch .

> error ./style.scss (Line 1: File to
> import not found or unreadable:
> normalize. Load path:
> /home/ternov/sass-test)

Естественно, если сам файл scss поместить рядом с normalize, все увидит и скомпилит.